# Index blank string python

Tags: python

The below functions works as I want but if the argument contains a blank string within the list it doesn't index as I hoped it would.

```
def number(lines):
    return ['{0}: '.format(lines.index(i) +1) + i for i in lines]



print(number(["a", "b", "c"]))
```

returns:

```
["1: a", "2: b", "3: c"]
```

exactly how I want it to return the list

however if the argument for the function contains a string that is blank for example:

```
print(number(["a", "", ""]))
```

returns:

```
["1: a", "2: ", "2: "]
```

Can someone explain why this happens, and how I can correct it to always count up from one regardless of a list element is blank

Comment: it's because the length of list is 3, so it will return length of 3 list.

Comment: @JayParikh that's not true at all. If something cannot be found in the list, then you get `ValueError` on `index()`. What circumstances would result in it defaulting to the length of the list here?

Comment: that's not gonna happen in this case atleast because he is checking the same item in the same array. @roganjosh Hope it is clear !

Comment: @JayParikh you said "it's because the length of list is 3, so it will return length of 3 list.". I'm saying this isn't correct.

Comment: i used this statement for this example. @roganjosh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `index` method gives you the *first* index where the space appears in the list. This isn't limited to just empty strings, but any character/string that appears twice in the list. Use `enumerate` to have a counting variable instead.

```
def number(lines):
    return ['{0}: {1}'.format(i+1, j) for i, j in enumerate(lines)]
```

Comment: Thanks that's great

Answer (score 0):

if you dont want blank string then try

```
    return ['{0}: '.format(lines.index(i) +1) + i for i in lines if i!='']
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible working solution:

```
def number(lines):
    return ['{0}: {1}'.format(i + 1, l) for i, l in enumerate(lines) if l.strip() != ""]
```